# Problem 2.18: Algebraic curves - William Fulton

Tags: algebraic-geometry

**Problem:** Let $\mathcal{O}_P(V)$ be a local ring of a manifold $V$ at a point $P$. Show that there is a bijection between the prime ideals in $\mathcal{O}_P(V)$ and the submanifolds of $V$ that pass through $P$.

**Solution proposal:** Initially, see the following:

$\bullet$ ***Affirmation***: If $I$ is prime ideal in $\mathcal{O}_p(V)$, then $I \cap \Gamma(V)$ is prime ideal in $\Gamma(V) )$;

In fact, let $f,g \in \Gamma(V)$ such that $f \cdot g \in I \cap \Gamma(V)$. Since $I$ is a prime ideal in $\mathcal{O}_p(V)$, follows that
$$f \in I \cap \Gamma(V) \ \ \mbox{or} \ \ g \in I \cap \Gamma(V),$$
that is, $I \cap \Gamma(V)$ is a prime ideal in $\Gamma(V)$.

Now, remember the following fact:

$\bullet$ ***Fact***: There is a natural bijection between submanifolds $V$ and prime ideals in $\Gamma(V)$. (See Problem 2.2 in [http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/%7Ewfulton/CurveBook.pdf))

Thus, by ***Affirmation***, it follows that
$$\stackrel{ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ I}{\small{Ideal \ prime \ in \ \mathcal{O}_P(V)} \ } \longrightarrow \stackrel{ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ I \cap \Gamma(V)}{\small{\ Ideal \ prime \ in \ \Gamma(V) \ }}.$$

Now, in view of the ***Fact***, we can reorder the matches so that
$$\stackrel{ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ I \cap \Gamma(V)}{\small{\ Ideal \ prime \ in \ \Gamma(V)}} \longrightarrow \stackrel{ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ V'}{\ \small{Subvariety \ of \ V \ which \ passes \ in \ P} \ }.$$

By the same argument as before, it follows from ***Fact*** that
$$\stackrel{ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ V'}{\small{\ Subvariety \ of \ V \ that \ passes \ in \ P}\ } \longrightarrow \stackrel{ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ I \cap \Gamma(V)}{\small{\ Ideal \ prime \ in \ \Gamma(V) \ }},$$
with $I$ prime ideal $\mathcal{O}_P(V)$. So as we have the natural correspondence

$$\stackrel{ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ I \cap \Gamma(V)}{\small{\ Ideal \ prime \ in \ \Gamma(V)} \ } \longrightarrow \stackrel{ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ I}{ \small{\ Ideal \ prime \ in \ \mathcal{O}_P(V)} \ } \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$

it follows that there is a bijection between the prime ideals in $\mathcal{O}_P(V)$ and the submanifolds of $V$ that pass through $P$.

$$**DOUBT**$$

In order for the correspondence in (1) to be well defined, the following suggestion is proposed: If $I$ is a prime ideal in $\mathcal{O}_P(V)$, then $I$ is generated by $I \cap \Gamma(V)$. How can I prove this tip? Can you help me?

Comment: What is $\Gamma(V)$?

Comment: We let $\Gamma(V) = \frac{k[X_1, \ldots ,X_n]}{I(V)}$ and call it the coordinate ring of $V$. For more details, see http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf.